# Pyspark and phoenix table

Tags: pyspark, classnotfoundexception, apache-phoenix

I would like to use the phoenix tables with Pyspark. I try the solution that i found here: https://phoenix.apache.org/phoenix_spark.html

But I have an error. Can you help me to solve this error?

```
df_metadata = sqlCtx.read.format("org.apache.phoenix.spark").option("zkUrl", "xxx").load("lib.name_of_table")
print(df_metadata.collect())
```

and the error:

py4j.protocol.Py4JJavaError: An error occurred while calling o103.load.
: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Failed to find data source: org.apache.phoenix.spark. Please find packages at http://spark-packages.org

How can I use org.apache.phoenix.spark with pyspark?

Comment: Step 1... To ensure that all requisite Phoenix / HBase platform dependencies are available on the classpath for the Spark executors and drivers, set both ‘spark.executor.extraClassPath’ and ‘spark.driver.extraClassPath’ in spark-defaults.conf to include the ‘phoenix-<version>-client-spark.jar’

Comment: --conf "spark.executor.extraClassPath=/opt/apache-phoenix-X.X.X-HBase-X.X-bin/phoenix-X.X.X-HBase-X.X-client.jar"\
        --conf "spark.driver.extraClassPath=/opt/apache-phoenix-X.X.X-HBase-X.X-bin/phoenix-X.X.X-HBase-X.X-client.jar"\ I add these lines in my Spark Submit. But i don't understand the step 2...

Comment: Step 2 is if you are using Maven within Java / Scala, I think

Comment: I add the two lines in spark submit. And when I print my dataframa I have a dataframe. But when I print + collect() I have an error: `df_metadata = sqlCtx.read.format("org.apache.phoenix.spark").option("table","name").option("zkUrl", "XXX").load()
print(df_metadata)
print(df_metadata.first())` and now the error: `DataFrame[PRICE: string]` ok this my dataframe but when i want to print and collect(): `py4j.protocol.Py4JJavaError: An error occurred while calling z:org.apache.spark.sql.execution.EvaluatePython.takeAndServe.
: org.apache.spark.SparkException: Job aborted due to stage failure:`

Comment: and `java.lang.IllegalStateException: unread block data`

Comment: You can [edit] your question with your full code and stacktrace

Comment: How can I use org.apache.phoenix.spark with pyspark?

Comment: Yes, I read your question... There's no need to comment with it again

Comment: Errors look familiar? This is how to use spark-csv... Same logic applies to Phoenix and any other spark libraries http://datascience.stackexchange.com/questions/9943/use-spark-csv-inside-jupyter-and-using-python

Answer (score 2, accepted):

OK I found how correct this code:
I add this part in my spark-submit:
--jars /opt/phoenix-4.8.1-HBase-1.2/phoenix-spark-4.8.1-HBase-1.2.jar,/opt/phoenix-4.8.1-HBase-1.2/phoenix-4.8.1-HBase-1.2-client.jar \

Answer (score 0):

I know the answer given by @Zop works.

I've got this error `py4j.protocol.Py4JJavaError: An error occurred while calling o53.load.
: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Failed to find data source: org.apache.phoenix.spark. Please find packages at http://spark.apache.org/third-party-projects.html`

You can do it this way too

```
spark-submit --jars /usr/hdp/current/phoenix-client/phoenix-spark2.jar,/usr/hdp/current/phoenix-client/phoenix-4.7.0.2.6.4.0-91-client.jar,/usr/hdp/current/phoenix-client/phoenix-4.7.0.2.6.4.0-91-server.jar  <file here>
```

Comment: how to do in in jupyter notebook

Comment: You'll have to type this in the terminal or in the environment in which your jupyter notebook is running.